# Helium in an old mylar balloon

Tags: ideal-gas, home-experiment, diffusion

As a sealed mylar foil balloon ages, it deflates. I assume that this is mostly due to the monoatomic helium escaping through the envelope material. (In much the same manner as hydrogen can escape sealed tanks.)

Because commercially available helium is cut with air, (to reduce costs, conserve supply, and prevent asphyxiation.) the larger molecules that make up air are left behind inside the balloon envelope when it deflates.

If I want to find the helium content by volume after some time *t*, I assume that I can play around with the ideal gas law a bit. A problem arises, however, because I don't know how fast I'm losing helium ($\frac{dn}{dt}$) or pressure ($\frac{dP}{dt}$, although I generally know the starting pressure).

Does anyone know where to find or *how* to find those numbers without laboratory or industrial equipment?

Answer (score 1):

Asymptotically the balloon should contain only air. The ratio of initial to final volume gives you the air fraction (by number). Once you know that it is easy to fit an exponential plus constant to the measured volume as a function of time.

You can attempt the free fit of both the exponential and the constant with data from a limited period, but the fitting error will necessarily be worse and the covariance matrix will be non-trivial until you get out to several lifetimes.

Comment: Well yes, but what if I don't want to wait several weeks for the balloon to deflate?

Comment: Well, that's harder.

Comment: Yup. I was trying to think of a way to work it out by looking up the properties of metalized mylar, but I don't have the slightest idea where to start. A related question that would require similar reasoning would be "how quickly does hydrogen escape from a sealed metal tank?"

Comment: Doing it from first principles is *hard* because it depends roughly exponentially on the thickness of the material (treating it as a tunneling problem), and even small manufacturing variation can leave you hugely off.

Comment: True.. but how small of a manufacturing variation are you describing? If you assume the wall width is uniform within ~0.01mm, I wouldn't have expected that the variation would throw you off.

Comment: I believe the mylar material is manufactured in a similar fashion to plate glass so I would expect there to be the same kind of "waves" in it. But at the same time, when the average envelope thickness is less than or equal to the width of a piece of paper, is the manufacturing variation still significant? (Not challenging your expertise, just honestly wondering if it would make much difference at that scale.)